# iOS Magic Keyboard APIs

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ipad

Is it possible to intercept the trackpad events from the magic keyboard (with trackpad) in an iOS app and process them myself while hiding the pointer and not sending these events to the UI, or is that not possible?

Think about a game for instance where the user would move their finger around on the trackpad to move a character around on screen, but you wouldn't want to show the pointer circle and the location on the screen doesn't matter or if/where they click, you are just using the change in position as they move their finger on the trackpad.

Thanks

Comment: Look at UIPanGestureRecognizer with `allowedScrollTypesMask` set to `.all`. You can examine the event type for `.scroll`. What you do with it is totally up to you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean actually scrolling (i.e. two fingers), I meant to say they are just moving their finger around on the trackpad, which would be a panning gesture. Is it possible to intercept and block that gesture coming from the trackpad but not from the screen?

Comment: Again, a gesture is a gesture. I don't know what you mean by "intercept" or "block": the gesture has the meaning that you give it. You have total ability to receive touches at any level (raw touches, gesture recognizer, etc.). The fact that it's a trackpad makes no difference, but you can _detect_ that it's a trackpad if desired.